# Filtering a php array using binary

Tags: php, arrays, binary, filtering

A have a php array

```
$arr = array(
     1  => "a", 
     2  => "b", 
     4  => "c", 
     8  => "d",
     16 => "e", 
     32 => "f"
);
```

and a binary number

```
$filter=101101
```

I want to filter the array and keep only the keys where the respective value on binary is 1
For this example I would have:

```
$arr = array(
     1  => "a", 
     4  => "c", 
     8  => "d",
     32 => "f"
);
```

Or for

```
$filter=110001
```

to get

```
$arr = array(
     1  => "a", 
     2  => "b", 
     32 => "f"
);
```

Comment: Why are you referencing them using binary form rather than using a normal count in your array keys?

Comment: Actually $filter is stored as decimal. So 101101 is stored as 45 and 110001 is 35. It is a sort way. What do you mean by normal count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the length of `$filter` is always the same as the number of array elements:

```
$filter_arr = str_split($filter);
$new_arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($filter_arr[$i] == 1) {
        $new_arr[$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Using your given array, and filter equal to 101101, `$new_arr` will equal:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [4] => c
    [8] => d
    [32] => f
)
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/N8waffGz)

Comment: Yes, the number of array elements is always the same with the length of $filter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
         1  => "a", 
         2  => "b", 
         4  => "c", 
         8  => "d",
         16 => "e", 
         32 => "f"
    );

    $filter=110001;
    $filerValue = str_split($filter);
    $count = 0;

    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        if($filerValue[$count] == 0)
            unset($arr[$k]);
        $count++;
    }

    var_dump($arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
    array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "b"
      [32]=>
      string(1) "f"
    }
```